# Response not converted according to my custom response class in Spring 4.3.0

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have extended ResponseEntity  class and made a custom class with a constructor.

```
But in Spring 3 and Spring 4 JSON format is different.
```

1) In Spring 4 :

```
[
  {
    "communityTypeId": 1,
    "communityTypeName": "Indian"
  }
]
```

2) In Spring 3 :

```
{
  "headers": {},
  "body": [
      {
        "communityTypeId": 1,
        "communityTypeName": "Indian"
      }
   ]
}
```

My controller Method is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getcommunity")
    public @ResponseBody CultureRideResponseEntity getCommunity() {
        try {
            List<CommunityType> communityTypeList = iCommunityTypeService.getList();
            if (communityTypeList != null && communityTypeList.size() > 0)
                return new CultureRideResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK, communityTypeList);
            return new CultureRideResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT, CulturerideConstant.NO_COMMUNITY_FOUND);
        } catch (CultureRideException ex) {
            return new CultureRideResponseEntity(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED, ex.errorMessage());
        }
    }
```

And Response entity class is which i have created to extend ResponseEntity:

```
public class CultureRideResponseEntity extends ResponseEntity<Object> {    

    // String Property is used to store error message
    private String message;

    public CultureRideResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, Object data) {
        super(data, status);
        log.debug("response data:", data);
    }

    public CultureRideResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, Exception ex) {
        super(null, status);
        message = ex.getMessage();
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    public CultureRideResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, String msg) {
        super(null, status);
        setMessage(msg);
        log.debug("response data:", msg);
    }

    public CultureRideResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, Object data, String msg) {
        super(data, status);
        setMessage(msg);
        log.debug("response data:", data);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: Please provide your `RequestMapping` method and controller class also

Comment: @RamanujanR I have added controller method and response entity class. Pls have a look.

Comment: What is the minor version of spring 3?

Comment: @Zorglube my question is -> I want spring 4 will return JSON data as like spring 3 return.

Answer (score 2):

Why have you extended ResponseEntity, that seems like a strange thing to do?

In any case ResponseEntity (HttpEntity) has a getHeaders() in Spring 4, and this seems to be serialized as part of the JSON.

It looks like the extension is created to facilitate error handling, this is normally done using an @ExceptionHandler annotated method, and returning another ResponseEntity with the appropriate error code.

Answer (score 0):

I have create my own cutome class without extend ResponseEntity. Now the result is good what i want.

```
public class TestResponseEntity {    

        // String Property is used to store error message
        private String message;

        private Object body;

        private String message;

        public TestResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, Object data) {
            this.statusCode = status.name();
            this.body = data;
            log.debug("response data:", data);
        }

        public TestResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, Exception ex) {
            this.statusCode = status.name();
            this.message = ex.getMessage();
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        public TestResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, String msg) {
           this.statusCode = status.name();
           this.message = msg;
            log.debug("response data:", msg);
        }

        public TestResponseEntity(HttpStatus status, Object data, String msg) {
          this.statusCode = status.name();
          this.body = data;
          this.message = msg;
            log.debug("response data:", data);
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```